# Python IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, python, chmod

I want to write string character to file, but i get error like this `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/python/add.txt'`. how to solve this?

this is my code

```
q = open('/python/add.txt','r')
a = ['123', '234', '456']
lst = []
for line in q:
    for word in a:
        if word in line:
            line = line.replace(word + "\n",'')
    lst.append(line)
q.close()
z = open(r'/python/add.txt','w+')
for line in lst:
    z.write(line)
z.close()
```

Comment: You will need to chose a location for the `add.txt` file that is writable by the user who is running the code - usually that would be somewhere in the user's `$HOME` directory (like `/home/username/Documents`)

Comment: Why do you feel a need to store data in a directory under the Root-directory of the file system? There is typically very little reason to do so...
When opening file in Python, it is way better to use the `with` statement. Python will take care than that the file is closed automatically when no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 choices:

- Run your script as root user. I.e.:

  `sudo ./path/to/your/script.py` or `sudo python3 path/to/your/script.py`
- Grant read, write & execute permissions to /python and read & write permissions to /python/add.txt for your user/group. There are a few ways to reach that ends, e.g.:

  `sudo chown -R my_user:my_user /python && sudo chmod u+rw /python/add.txt`
- Put `add.txt` somewhere else (as per @steeldriver's comment) such as within your users `$HOME`.